# How to estimate amount of memory needed for binary classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest

Say I wanna create a binary classifier for detecting SPAM messages. I have a billion of training examples and about 20 features. I want my trained classifier to fit in memory (I will run it on cloud and disk operations which are actually rpc-calls will be *very* expensive).

My question is: how can I estimate the amount of memory I'll need for it? Say my classifier is Random Forest and I know nothing about distribution of SPAM messages in my training set.

Only numbers: two classes, billion examples, 20 features.

Is such an estimation possible at all? How can it be done?

Comment: Are you trying to fit the billion training examples in memory or fit the trained model in memory?

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan: Fit the trained model in memory and run classification in real time.

Comment: Well that would depend theoretically on the size of size of the trees and practically on the actual implementation.

Answer (score 2):

For spam classification you should probably run a linear classifier on word occurrences features + bigrams + domain names or ip addresses occurring in links + stuff extracted from the headers and the SMTP context.

In that case you can hash the features on 2 ** 18 dimensions (using [vowpal wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki) for instance) times 8 bytes per features that makes you a 2MB model in memory.